# ¿Como puedo cargar un select en un array y mostrarlo por consola?

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo una tabla en la cual ingreso varios inputs de tipo texto a un array por su nombre de clase , al momento de mostrar los datos en la consola , se muestran los datos, pero el dato del `select` no y no se porque.

```js
function selecciones(){

    let lstNumero = document.getElementsByClassName("numero"),
        arrayGuardar = [];         
    for (var i = 0; i < lstNumero.length; i++) {    
        arrayGuardar[i] = lstNumero[i].value;
        console.log (lstNumero[i].value);     
        }  
       
   
    }
```

```html
Nacionalidad:
<input type="text" name="zipCode2" id="zipCode2" class="numero">
Nombre:
<input type="text" name="city2" id="city2" class="numero">
Edad:
<input type="text" name="state2" id="state2" class="numero">
Altura:
<input type="text" name="state2" id="HEIGHT2" class="numero">
Posicion:
<select name="country2" id="country2" class="numero"><option value="">Seleccione...</option><option value="">Portero</option><option value="">Defensa central</option><option value="">Lateral</option><option value="">Carrilero</option><option value="">Líbero o libre</option><option value="">Pivote</option><option value="">Interior</option>Media punta</option><option value="">Volante</option><option value="">Extremo</option><option value="">Segundo delantero</option><option value="">Delantero centro</option></select>
        
        <input type="button" value="Capturar" onclick="selecciones()">
```

Comment: Buen día, en tu `select` todas las opciones tienen `value` vacío... no sé qué necesites utilizar de valores pero por ejemplo yo puse la primera opción así: `<option value="0">Seleccione...</option>`. También te hace falta abrir un `option` para "Media punta"

Comment: @HeytalePazguato Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

```
<label>Nacionalidad:</label>
<input type="text" name="zipCode2" id="zipCode2" class="numero">

<label>Nombre:</label>
<input type="text" name="city2" id="city2" class="numero" value="Test">

<label>Edad:</label>
<input type="text" name="state2" id="state2" class="numero">

<label>Altura:</label>
<input type="text" name="state2" id="HEIGHT2" class="numero">

<label>Posicion:</label>
<select name="country2" id="country2" class="numero"><option value="">Seleccione...</option><option value="Portero">Portero</option><option value="Defensa">Defensa central</option><option value="Lateral">Lateral</option><option value="Carrilero">Carrilero</option><option value="Líbero o libre">Líbero o libre</option><option value="Pivote">Pivote</option><option value="Interior">Interior</option>Media punta</option><option value="Volante">Volante</option><option value="Extremo">Extremo</option><option value="Segundo delantero">Segundo delantero</option><option value="Delantero centro">Delantero centro</option></select>
        
<input type="button" value="Capturar" onclick="selecciones()">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias tambien!!